# onChange Switch Handler

Tags: javascript, react.js, typescript

In react I have a HTML Element Factory, it allows several different types of form elements to be created most with the same onChange but some have specific uses. I have been capturing them in this switch, but its time to refactor, what should an onChange() switch be converted to, should this too be a factory? Or just a object literal with functions? Or should I use a Factory Function here?

Some rough code advice would be very useful.

```
 const onChange = (event: any, tags: any, formEl: any) => {
    setLayout(
      layout?.map((el: IElement) => {
        if (el.id === formEl.id) {
          switch (formEl.type) {
            case "autocomplete" :
            case "autocompletewide": {
              if (event.target.getAttribute("data-option-index") !== null) {
                el.value =
                  formEl.options[
                    event.target.getAttribute("data-option-index")
                  ].id;
                return el;
              } else {
                el.value = "";
                return el;
              }
            }
            case "autocompletemulti": {
              if (tags.length) {
                const vals: string = tags.map((tag: IOption) => tag.id);
                el.value = vals.toString();
                return el;
              } else {
                el.value = "";
                return el;
              }
            }
            case "datepicker": {
              let dateValue: Date | null = event;
              if (dateValue !== null)
                el.value = dateValue?.toISOString().substr(0, 10);
              else el.value = "";
              return el;
            }
            default: {
              el.value = event.target.value;
              return el;
            }
          }
        } else {
          return el;
        }
      })
    );
  };
```

Comment: The current question title of your question is too generic to be helpful. Please edit to the site standard, which is for the title to simply **state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).